# Creating pseudo-heatmap based on time spent in AOI using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, imagery

I wanted to see if there was a way to create a heatmap based on time spent in a certain AOI.  What I mean by this is a layer you can toggle on/off that would go from clear to red as you spend more time looking at a certain point.

My reason for this is a good number of people at my company struggle to know where they've already been when we're working with large AOIs and large data sets; it can't get tricky to make sure you've reviewed such a large swath of imagery.
Ideally this layer would be clear but as you move around in the imagery it would make darker patches where you've been.  Maybe this could be based on cursor movement; however, I don't think that's the best option.

I don't actually know whether or not this is feasible but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: *Is it possible* questions suffer from the fact that most things are possible, but that a Boolean answer wouldn't be of much use. I can see several possible approaches to such a solution, but feasibility is more dependent on level of effort and factors not addressed by the question. Have you been tasked with finding a solution? There are many possibilities though the use of a plugin, but that would probably require management buy-in and additional training. I think this may be *too broad* for GIS SE.

Comment: If re-worded as a "how to do it" question instead of "is it possible," this would be a a decent question. It definitely needs more detail, though. Specifically, what are the users *doing* when they "work with large AOIs"? It might be easier to count the number of times users perform a certain action, eg clicking on something. Or you could create a grid, and have users manually mark each section of the grid as "finished" or "visited" or "number of times visited" or something like that. The more specific you can be, the more reasonable and implementable a solution we can come up with.

Comment: @csk Essentially what they're working with is feature data collection in an area that is in the tens of sq. KM.  I like your idea of making a grid layer that they can toggle on and off and mark a square as "done" after completing all collection in that boundary.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If they're creating features as they work, you could also set up the grid's transparency or color based on the number of features in the grid square. (At least I *think* you can do this in ArcGIS; I know it's possible in QGIS with the `intersecting_geom_count()` function in a virtual field.) Should be much more efficient than creating a custom script that "watches" you as you work.

Comment: Just add a grid to the project, that's what I do. Then either strictly go through each row when working with the data, or even add a style to the grid which allows people to turn places they already worked on intransparent.

Answer (score 0):

To do this I think you would need to solve a number of problems.

I think that the first of these would be to record, perhaps as a feature class of rectangular polygons, each extent visited by your users.

This would mean having each extent change trigger the capture of that extent polygon.

Then you would also need to capture the time each extent was on screen, and probably whether your user was looking at the screen for all of that time.

All in all, if this is possible, then it is far from trivial to do.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible certainly, it's not feasible unless you have some serious R&D time and budget. In apps that handle this well, there needs to be a native handler for interactions, such as the onclick event from HTML. As Arc is not natively able to run custom code on top of the map, you would probably have to do this with ArcEngine running in a java environment, where java handles the interactions, or using (creating) a plugin that uses java or python to watch for extent changes and record them to a feature class...a non trivial interaction on a cpu, by the way.

More realistically, try using Map Books to develop an indexed grid and then iteratively go through and work over your area by index number. I used this method for large spatial geometries that needed feature validation, and it was relatively efficient while lowering implementation time. Having map books numbered also allows others to work alongside much more easily, if they are assigned an area by number rather than randomly.